# Object not found using Xampp

Tags: php, database, xampp

i am facing error by using Xampp server
error is:

```
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2s PHP/7.1.33
```

my all files are locate in htdocs 
  [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNabt.png)

index.php opened successfully but when i can move from another page school.php, contact.php, about.php its give me error 
kindle tell me reason behind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XAMPP sets a default as Program Files/Xampp/Htdocs/xampp

YOU ARE ALREADY IN HTDOCS…

try doing ahref=…/ in your directory…see if that works, if not…

try editing your xampp.conf file.

it is located in your xampp/apache folder
mine is (C:/Program Files/Xampp/Apache/conf/extra/xampp.conf)
(it might actually be xampp.htconf or something, but you’ll see it…its the only one with the xampp)…

copy the PhpMyAdmin section, and paste it below.

change the /phpmyadmin to /htdocs or whatever you want to beshown after http://localhost 633.

Then you’ll need to set up the doc root as well, this just tells apache where to serve the file from…

DONT SET UP as HTDOCS though because apache will go in a huge loop and consume all your CPU…i know i’ve tried.

anyway, i have a couple set up…

my document root is soemthing like:

c:/program files/xampp/htdocs/production/kreative

so you will see my main site,
but i have also set up
/phpmyadmin
/xampp
/development(which goes to c:/program files/xampp/htdocs/xampp/development).

Its nice if you add an .htacessfile to those directories you want to use
(like for me the phpmyadmin etc…don’t want my visitors using those).

Hope this helps.
```